# Free solver for MINLP

Tags: optimization, solver, pyomo, ampl, asl

I am trying to solve a MINLP and I use Pyomo and Spyder. I am looking for a free global solver for many variables and constraints and it should be matched with Pyomo.
Baron is a global solver but it needs license for more than 10 variables and 10 constraints. I used Knitro solver but it is a local solver and it was stuck in local optimum.
Which solver do you recommend?

Comment: [Couenne](https://projects.coin-or.org/Couenne) But don't expect magic for *many variables and constraints*.

Comment: @sascha I used Couenne but the result is not global optimum!! Is it possible that the result of a global server don't be a global optimum?!!